# using namespace for function-member definition

Tags: c++, namespaces, language-lawyer

I have the following class definition in `.h` file:

```
namespace N {
    struct S {
        S(); // no definition for member here    
    };
}
```

And I would like to write definition for class constructor (member in general) in `.cpp` file. I consider the following two cases:

1. ```
   namespace N {
       S::S() { /* definition */ }  
   }
   ```
2. ```
   using namespace N;
   S::S() { /* definition */ }
   ```

I'm slightly confused why the second is working at all, because never saw this way definition until today. Why the second is working? Some citing from the Standard would be appreciated.

What are the nuances of using one approach instead of the other? Should I prefer the first or the second form?

Comment: I would have been very surprised if (2) did *not* work.  Clearly (1) and scoping in general is preferred.

Comment: http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lookup

Comment: @HenriMenke in my mind `using namespace` is for "using" actually, i.e. calling functions, using variables etc, but not for definition. E.g. you can't define a class same way.

Comment: Yes, but not limted. “The declarations from the namespace nominated by a using-directive become visible in a namespace enclosing the using-directive;”  A namespace can also be the global namespace of the translation unit.

Comment: I think you have to use the second version for unnamed namespace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason (2) works is because of these two:

1. [[class.mfct]/4](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.mfct#4)

   > If the definition of a member function is lexically outside its class
   >   definition, the member function name shall be qualified by its class
   >   name using the ​::​ operator.
2. [[namespace.udir]/2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/namespace.udir#2) (emphasis mine)

   > A using-directive specifies that **the names in the nominated namespace
   >   can be used in the scope in which the using-directive appears after
   >   the using-directive**. During unqualified name lookup, the names appear
   >   as if they were declared in the nearest enclosing namespace which
   >   contains both the using-directive and the nominated namespace. [ Note:
   >   In this context, “contains” means “contains directly or indirectly”.
   >    — end note ]

The directive simply lets you name `S` for the `::` operator as if you were inside the `N` namespace (as you are in (1)). But I wouldn't do that. Scoping is good. Definitions should be scoped too.

Answer (score 0):

In this particular example you have declared only one structure in the namespace and defined the function in a separate .cpp file, so it doesn't matter if you use 1 or 2.

Had you declared any other identifiers in the namespace, then 1 should be preferred over 2 as the using declaration kind of defeats the purpose of having a namespace.